# combine 2 numbers to be date C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have 2 integers look like

```
int month = 3;
int year = 2006;
```

How can I join them to be like:

```
03/2006 datetime
```

and this date format as "mm/yyyy"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a `DateTime()` and then use the `.ToString` overload that gives you to specify a format:

```
new DateTime(year, month, 1).ToString("MM/yyyy");
```

Read on MSDN for the [different formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) options

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a date with it to create datetime

```
int month = 03;
int year = 2006;

DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
```

then you can get it as `mm/yyyy` format string

```
string s = dt.ToString("MM/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 1):

To form just a `String` you can try [*string interpolation*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) *(available from c# 6.0)*, e.g.

```
  int month = 3;
  int year = 2006;

  string s = $"{month:00}/{year}";
```

In case you want `DateTime`, not `String`:

```
  DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
```

To represent `DateTime` created in `mm/yyyy` format":

```
  string s = $"{dt:MM/yyyy}";
```